# Angular application not running under WPF Web browser

Tags: angular, wpf

> Angular web Application is not running under WPF browser

Comment: please add more details, like what did you try, did you get any error  ?

Comment: i have developed an angular web application and WPF application, i want to open in angular website with in  WPF application (web browser), all other websites are open easily but only angular website not open

Comment: He won't get an error. It just won't run. Nothing in angular will work.  There is no more information he can provide is necessary to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

The webbrowser control is a thin wrapper around internet explorer.

Due to security concerns, the ie mode it runs under is ie7.

That means BIG PROBLEMS for any and all modern javascript frameworks. Because they are written by people who don't concern themselves with backward compatibility to ancient browsers. They live in a world where everyone they know uses all the latest versions of browsers.

There are several options you can try to force it to use ie11 mode.

The most elegant is to use a meta tag on your pages.

This goes in the head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

I recommend double checking the actual tag, I'm not sure whether that should be 11 or Edge. ( Which translates to latest rather than the edge browser ).

Or you can set an entry in the registry on machines. This is rarely practical most sites I've worked though.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Those are the "old" ways of doing this.

Nowadays I would be more inclined to use a xaml island webview control which is a wrapper around Edge. The browser.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview

Comment: Please do not answer questions like this where the OP has made zero effort. It just makes them go on to ask [even more low-effort questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383035/protect-existing-pdf-file-in-folder-with-password-and-email-as-attachment-in-asp) and degrades the quality of the site as a whole.